# How to apply none to display after running an animation?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a table, and I remove the elements dynamically through a filter.

[image]

I want to add some fading animation to the elements, but if I just fade them out, I get a horrible and unnecessary gap. I need to apply a "display: none", but animations don't work with "display: none".

So, how do I sequentially fade something by first applying a fading animation, followed by a "display: none"?

Comment: Take a look at **keyframes** (css)

Comment: Have you tried jQuery's fadeOut() method? ( Ex: jQuery('#element').fadeOut(); ) This adjusts the opacity to zero then sets display:none.

Comment: @DerekGutierrez since this question isn't tagged with jQuery, it shouldn't be offered as a solution.

Comment: @DerekGutierrez, I use react.

Comment: @MichaelBianconi's answer would be a better approach in that case. I mentioned jQuery (Javascript Library) as solution since there was no example code to reference and it could be done in a one liner otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Use **keyframes**:

```css
.show {
    display: block;
    animation: fadeInFromNone 0.2s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.hide {
    display: block;
    animation: fadeOutFromBlock 0.2s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeInFromNone {
      0% { display: none;  opacity: 0; }
      1% { display: block; opacity: 0; }
    100% { display: block; opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes fadeOutFromBlock {
      0% { display: block; opacity: 1;    }
     99% { display: block; opacity: 0.01; }
    100% { display: none;  opacity: 0;    }
}
```

Be aware that animations often need vender specific specifiers (`-moz`, `-webkit`, etc).

Comment: Display none doesn't get applied at the end of the animation.

Comment: Have you implemented the vendor specific versions? This copy paste what I use to fade in/out my modals.